# us states dropdown function and echo in theme template files

Tags: functions, themes, templates, search, forms

This may seem like a stupid question but for whatever reason I cant find an answer that works for me.. -- I am trying to create a simple html drop down function in functions.php so I can then echo it out on a search form. I tried add_action and apply_filters and still couldnt get it to echo out on my form.

Functions -

```
function state_dropdown() {
    echo "<select id='state' name='state'>

<option value='AL'>Alabama</option>
<option value='AK'>Alaska</option>
<option value='AZ'>Arizona</option>
<option value='AR'>Arkansas</option>
<option value='CA'>California</option>

<option value='CO'>Colorado</option>
<option value='CT'>Connecticut</option>
<option value='DE'>Delaware</option>
<option value='DC'>District of Columbia</option>
<option value='FL'>Florida</option>

<option value='GA'>Georgia</option>
<option value='HI'>Hawaii</option>
<option value='ID'>Idaho</option>
<option value='IL'>Illinois</option>
<option value='IN'>Indiana</option>

<option value='IA'>Iowa</option>
<option value='KS'>Kansas</option>
<option value='KY'>Kentucky</option>
<option value='LA'>Louisiana</option>
<option value='ME'>Maine</option>

<option value='MD'>Maryland</option>
<option value='MA'>Massachusetts</option>
<option value='MI'>Michigan</option>
<option value='MN'>Minnesota</option>
<option value='MS'>Mississippi</option>

<option value='MO'>Missouri</option>
<option value='MT'>Montana</option>
<option value='NE'>Nebraska</option>
<option value='NV'>Nevada</option>
<option value='NH'>New Hampshire</option>

<option value='NJ'>New Jersey</option>
<option value='NM'>New Mexico</option>
<option value='NY'>New York</option>
<option value='NC'>North Carolina</option>
<option value='ND'>North Dakota</option>

<option value='OH'>Ohio</option>
<option value='OK'>Oklahoma</option>
<option value='OR'>Oregon</option>
<option value='PA'>Pennsylvania</option>
<option value='RI'>Rhode Island</option>

<option value='SC'>South Carolina</option>
<option value='SD'>South Dakota</option>
<option value='TN'>Tennessee</option>
<option value='TX'>Texas</option>
<option value='UT'>Utah</option>

<option value='VT'>Vermont</option>
<option value='VA'>Virginia</option>
<option value='WA'>Washington</option>
<option value='WV'>West Virginia</option>
<option value='WI'>Wisconsin</option>

<option value='WY'>Wyoming</option>
</select>";
}
```

Search Form -

```
<?php
global $state_dropdown;
echo $state_dropdown;
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a function, not a variable - you want:

```
<?php state_dropdown() ?>
```

Comment: when I use that though I get this -- Fatal error: Call to undefined function state_dropdown() in ...index.php on line 70

Comment: Are you sure you have that function in `functions.php`? What is your "search form" file and where are you loading it?

Comment: Yes, they way I have it in the question is exactly how I have it in my functions.php file. Im using a child theme if it makes a difference. The search form, right now I am coding the form from scratch and its on index.php. @TheDeadMedic